# What is wrong with my Ruby programming code?

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

This code is supposed to work. But every time I open it on Ruby, Ruby just closes almost immediately because it can't read something in the code. So obviously there's an error(s) in the code but I reviewed everything and couldn't seem to find it. I need some help to get this code working. Thank-you so much in advance!

```
puts 'Enter the number of the current month using the 12 months per year scale. Ex. January would be 1, February would be 2, March would be 3, etc...'
month=gets.chomp
case month
when '1'..'3'
fee='$45'
when'4'..'5'
fee='$55'
when'7'..'8'
fee='$65'
else
fee='$0.00'
end
puts'The fee to apply for the competition is ' + fee + '.00 when you apply on the date of today, ' + Time.now.to_s +'.'
puts 'If your fee came up as $0.00, then that is because the competition has ended. But do not worry, there is always next year!'
sleep 20
```

Comment: Run it on the command line and it won't "close immediately". That way you'll be able to see the error message.

Answer (score 4):

This is what Ruby tells me the syntax error is:

```
temp.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tUPLUS, expecting $end
... of today, ' + Time.now.to_s +'.'
```

Adding a space between the `+` and the `'.'` fixes the syntax error.

---

You could have figured this out yourself by running Ruby from the command line. I assume you're running Windows. To get to the command prompt, you can press <kbd>Windows key</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog. From there, you can type in `cmd` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to open command prompt. You can then use `cd` to change the current directory and `ruby` to run your Ruby script (assuming Ruby is in the `PATH`). Your session might look like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Madelyn Grewal> cd Desktop

C:\Documents and Settings\Madelyn Grewal\Desktop> ruby myscript.rb
myscript.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tUPLUS, expecting $end
... of today, ' + Time.now.to_s +'.'

C:\Documents and Settings\Madelyn Grewal\Desktop>
```